# How do I get around this issue in PyQt5?

Tags: python, oop, pyqt5

#### Consider the bare minimum example given below

```py
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name=''
        self.age=''

    def setinfo(self):
        self.name=input()
        self.age=input()

    def run(self):
        self.startWin=QWidget()
        self.setinfo()
        dnd=DragDrop('Drop Photo here',self.startWin)
        self.startWin.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def showWin(self,file_path):
        self.mainWin=QWidget()
        self.label1=QLabel(self.name,self.mainWin)
        self.label2=QLabel(self.age,self.mainWin)
        self.photo = QLabel(self.mainWin)
        pixmap = QPixmap(file_path)
        self.photo.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.mainWin.show()

class DragDrop(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, title, parent):
        super().__init__(title, parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasImage:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()
    
    def dropEvent(self, event):
        file_path = event.mimeData().urls()[0].toLocalFile()
        self.showWin(file_path)

app = QApplication([])
instance=Main()
instance.run()
```

Now, what I want is to call the showWin function of the Main class as soon as the file is dropped into the dnd (Drag and Drop QLabel) to show the name, age and photo of the person. But of course a call from DragDrop class won't work as the showWin function belongs to the Main class. I can't even make an object of that class and then call it because I want to make the changes in the already running instance.

How do I get over this situation?

#### What I have already tried:

I have tried passing a mutable datatype like a list into the constructor of the DragDrop class and make changes into the same. But the issue with this is that it will need another click on some button in the run function to use that path and call showWin. The second solution is through using `__get__` method to override the event methods for a QLabel object directly (without forming a class) in the run function. But I think that's too language specific. I'm trying to find a general OOPs based solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom signal. Create the signal in DragDrop and emit in `dropEvent`:

```
image_dropped = pyqtSignal(str)
def dropEvent(self, event):
    file_path = event.mimeData().urls()[0].toLocalFile()
    self.image_dropped.emit(file_path)
```

Connect the signal to `showWin` in Main:

```
def run(self):
    self.startWin=QWidget()
    self.setinfo()
    dnd=DragDrop('Drop Photo here',self.startWin)
    dnd.image_dropped.connect(self.showWin)
    self.startWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```